# Set focus on image by default

Tags: angularjs, froala

I use the froala editor. (using angular).

I want that the first image get focus on initialize.

When I open the editor I get the editor without focus

[image]

And I want it to be with the image toolbar
[image]

What  I need to write in the `"froalaEditor.initialized" event` for focusing the first image

Thanks!

Comment: See [MDN Web APIs Reference HTMLElement.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus).